# AHK: Comparing Two Txt Files

Tags: loops, autohotkey, file-read

So I'm doing billing for a doctors office, and we like to triple check that the flu shots we give are actually billed out. Right now, my AHK checks their entire chart for keys like the ICD-10 Code Z23, then checks for "Influenza". If it finds both of these, it adds the patients Medical Record Number to the age appropriate text file, either 65+ or Under 65. There are also paper sheets with 10 slots we record the MRNs by hand on, to double check. I want to create a script that will compare three files, a file of mixed MRNs (both 65+ and <65), and if the MRN is found in the mixed file, it should remove that line. (I've done a bunch of googling on the subject, but everyone is recommending using a library, something that would only slow down my program.) If the line isn't found, it should be left in the master file for my review. I cannot figure out how to remove lines, let alone a specific line. So far, to check the files against each other, I have this. In lieu of removing lines, I'm appending the unbilled numbers to a fourth text file, but ultimately, removing would be better.

```
FILENUM = 1
FILENU = 1
^L::
Loop
    {
    FileReadLine, MRN, E:\AHK & AHKS\flushot.txt, %LINENUM%
    If ErrorLevel
        {
        break
        }
    Else
        {
        Loop
            {
            FileReadLine, MRNc, E:\AHK & AHKS\Billed65+Flushots.txt, LINENU
            StringTrimRight, MRNc, 11
            If (MRN != MRNc)
                {
                LINENU++
                Match = 0
                }
            If (MRN == MRNc)
                Match = 1
            If ErrorLevel and Match = 0
                {
                FileAppend, MRN, E:\AHK & AHKS\Unbilledtester.txt
                LINENU = 1
                }
            If (Match = 1)
                GoTo Lab2

            }
        Lab2:
        Loop
            {
            FileReadLine, MRNc, E:\AHK & AHKS\BilledAdultFlushots.txt, LINENU
            StringTrimRight, MRNc, 11
            If (MRN != MRNc)
                {
                LINENU++
                Match = 0
                }
            If (MRN == MRNc)
                Match = 1
            If ErrorLevel and Match = 0
                FileAppend, MRN, E:\AHK & AHKS\Unbilledtester.txt
            If (Match = 1)
                GoTo Lab2

            }
        LINENUM++

        }
    }
```

UPDATE!!!!!!!

Alright, so I grabbed your code, and I've been trying to run a reverse check. You check the associative arrays of the Adult and Senior flushot text files for the MRNS in flushot.txt, then if not found they're added to unbilled. Below are several of my attempts to reverse that, and check for the MRNs in Adult and Senior in flushot.txt, and if not found, to add it to a file called notrecorded.txt so I know what people got flushots and the MA who didn't record it (by Primary Care Provider).

```
FlushotsBilled()
{
Root_Dir            := "E:\AHK & AHKS"
fName_Input         := "flushot.txt"
fName_Backup        := "flushot_old.txt"
fName_Output        := "unbilled.txt"
fName_Billed_Adult  := "billedAdultFlushots.txt"
fName_Billed_Senior := "billed65+Flushots.txt"
fName_Billed_NR     := "notrecorded.txt"
fName_Mixed     := "mixrecord.txt"  

SetWorkingDir %Root_Dir%
FileDelete, %fName_Output%

AdultFlu   := {}
SeniorFlu  := {}
GivenFluA  := {}
GivenFluB  := {}
Mixed      := {}

Loop, Read, %fName_Mixed%
    Mixed[A_LoopReadLine] := True   

Loop, Read, %fName_Billed_Adult%
    {
    ;Loop, Parse, A_LoopReadLine, `t
    ;   AdultFlu[A_LoopField] := True
    AdultFlu[A_LoopReadLine] := True
        If !Mixed[A_LoopReadLine]
            FileAppend, %A_LoopReadLine%`n, %fName_Mixed%
    }

Loop, Read, %fName_Billed_Senior%
    {
    ;Loop, Parse, A_LoopReadLine, `t
    ;   SeniorFlu[A_LoopField] := True
    SeniorFlu[A_LoopReadLine] := True
        If !Mixed[A_LoopReadLine]
            FileAppend, %A_LoopReadLine%`n, %fName_Mixed%
    }

Loop, Read, %fName_Input% ;check flushot.txt for
    If !AdultFlu[SubStr(A_LoopReadLine, 1, InStr(A_LoopReadLine,"`t"))] && !SeniorFlu[SubStr(A_LoopReadLine, 1, InStr(A_LoopReadLine,"`t"))]
    ;If !AdultFlu[A_LoopReadLine] && !SeniorFlu[A_LoopReadLine] ;flushot is checking the associated arrays
        FileAppend, %A_LoopReadLine%`n, %fName_Output% ;if not found, stick it into unbilled.

Loop, Read, %fName_Input%
    GivenFluA[A_LoopReadLine] := True



/*  Loop, Read, %fName_Billed_Senior%
    If !Mixed[A_LoopReadLine]
        FileAppend, %A_LoopReadLine%`n, %fName_Mixed%

Loop, Read, %fName_Billed_Adult%
    If !Mixed[A_LoopReadLine]
        FileAppend, %A_LoopReadLine%`n, %fName_Mixed%

Loop, Read, %fName_Mixed%
    Mixed[A_LoopReadLine] := True
*/
Loop, Read, %fName_Mixed%
    If !GivenFluA[SubStr(A_LoopReadLine, 1, InStr(A_LoopReadLine,"`t"))] ;a_Loopreadline is a line in mixed. it is looking through flushot.txt for that line, if it's there, it's givenflua's index
        Loop, Read, %fName_Billed_NR%
            If !GivenFluA[A_LoopReadLine]
                FileAppend, %A_LoopReadLine%`n




/*
Loop, Read, %fName_Input% ;read flushot
    If Mixed[A_LoopReadLine] Contains A_LoopReadLine ;check to see if each line in flushot is in mixed
        GivenFluA[Mixed[A_LoopReadLine]] := True ;Mixed[A_LoopReadLine]

Loop, Read, %fName_Billed_NR%
    If !GivenFluA[A_LoopReadLine]
        FileAppend GivenFluA[%A_LoopReadLine%], %fName_Billed_NR%
*/

;if readline is in mixed, but not in flushot, check to see if it's in notrecorded, if not, append it

/*
Loop, Read, %fName_Mixed% ;open up the mixed record
    IfNotInString, A_LoopReadLine, GivenFluA[A_LoopReadLine] ;see if inside each line, we can find the lines from flushot.txt, if not
        ;GivenFluB[GivenFluA[A_LoopReadLine]] := True ;if not we give the line from inside flushot to another associative array
        GivenFluB[A_LoopReadLine] := True ;lets try this, put the value 

Loop, Read, %fName_Mixed%
    IfInString, A_LoopReadLine, GivenFluA[A_LoopReadLine]
        GivenFluB[A_LoopReadLine]

Loop, Read, %fName_Billed_NR% ;open up not recorded
    IfNotInString, A_LoopReadLine, GivenFluB[A_LoopReadLine] ;see if inside each line we can find that line from
        FileAppend, %A_LoopReadLine%`n, %fName_Billed_NR%
*/
}
```

Comment: Just to try again (I'm doing this because you're smart and you helped me before, here's hoping) @Jim-U

Answer (score 0):

I think you were on the right track by creating an output file rather than deleting lines.  Text files are usually treated as streams, not fixed-record-length data files. Deleting lines is error prone and not efficient; you'd have to compact the file somehow.

How big are your files?  If there are only a few thousand patients, I would just load everything into associative arrays so we can use keyed lookups.

**Program**

```
^L:: medical_run()

medical_run()
{
  root_dir            := "E:\AHK & AHKS"
  fname_input         := "flushot.txt"
  fname_backup        := "flushot_old.txt"
  fname_temp_output   := "Unbilledtester.txt"
  fname_billed_adult  := "billedAdultFlushots.txt"
  fname_billed_senior := "billed65+Flushots.txt"

  SetWorkingDir %root_dir%
  FileDelete %fname_output%

  adults    := {}
  seniors   := {}
  unmatched := {}

  loop READ, %fname_billed_adult%
    adults[A_LoopReadLine] := true

  loop READ, %fname_billed_senior%
    seniors[A_LoopReadLine] := true

  loop READ, %fname_input%
    if !adults[A_LoopReadLine] && !seniors[A_LoopReadLine]
      unmatched[A_LoopReadLine] := true

  for code,dummy in unmatched
    FileAppend %code%`n, %fname_output%

  FileMove %fname_input%, %fname_backup%
  FileMove %fname_temp_output%, %fname_input%
}
```

billedAdultFlushots.txt

```
101
102
103
104
```

billed65+Flushots.txt

```
205
206
207
208
```

flushot.txt BEFORE

```
301
101
103
302
205
301
207
103
303
301
```

flushot.txt AFTER

```
301
302
303
```

Comment: The files aren't very big now, and the mixed file will be erased after every time I run this code. It probably won't ever get to more than 50, honestly. The other two however, will be kept as a permanent record of the flushots billed and their dates of injection. As to the size of the other two, couldn't we use some sort of chunk grab? Is there a way to find out how many lines in a file, and grab chunks at a time without the program freaking out if the last chunk is the "wrong" size? I'm familiar with arrays, but I don't know what an associative array is.

Comment: As to those last two lines, I've not seen that command before, but based on the output, are you erasing the entire flushot.txt at the end and dumping the contents of unbilledtester.txt into it?

Comment: Also, one last question, sorry if triple commenting is bad, but I've noticed you have the tendency to use functions over just putting the code into the hotkey itself, is this preference or does it give some sort of performance boost? (I realize it's a smarter way to code, because everything will work independently if this is done, and I did have to convert a large chunk of my code to a function because it was repeated too much and taking too much space.)

Comment: I use functions over code because that's just how I program.  I find it makes the code self documenting and makes it easier to refactor.

Comment: The last two lines [rename](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/FileMove.htm) files.  I rename flushot.txt to flushot_old.txt and rename the temporary file Unbilledtester.txt to flushot.txt.

Comment: I assume autohotkey implements "[loop READ](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/LoopReadFile.htm)" using a buffered stream so we shouldn't have to worry reading files in chunks. [Associative arrays](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Objects.htm) are also known as hashes. They are like regular arrays, but they are keyed on strings, integers or objects rather than indexed on integers.

Comment: Gotcha. I'm gonna grab it up, do some googling so I get it, and make use of it. Not to jerk you back and forth, but for my previous question, how would I go about checking for duplicates? Would I need a second array?

Comment: I updated the program. It now collects output records in a hash before writing the output file. This filters out any duplicate output lines.

Comment: oops, I'm sorry. There won't be any duplicates in the flushot texts. I mean my previous question regarding the diagnosis codes. The ICD-10 thing.

Comment: Also, though, for this one, sometimes not all of the MRNs who got flu shots make it into the master file. I'm gonna try to do this part myself, because it should just be backwards of what you did to check for the existing ones, but I'll probably end up needing help with it.

Comment: So I tried to get this working, now obviously, I can't use my real files, so I'm working with "tester2.txt," "tester3.txt," "mixtest.txt," and "unbilledtester.txt". I only used three different MRNs, and they're fake, but in tester2 I've got 112233, and tester3 has 112234, and mixtest has both of those plus 112235. mixtest does NOT update at all, and I'm not sure what's going wrong as the AHK history doesn't show anything but the code.

Comment: Also, the code essentially deletes a file and then the file isn't there for the next run of the program. I created a new folder, with almost no editing of your code, and made new files. Now, flushot.txt is updating, but it's not keeping the one MRN that isn't in either adult or 65+.

Comment: Alright, I got it working. It seems it doesn't work if flushot_old.txt still exists, which I'm not sure how to fix. I'm hesitant to use the code quite yet in a real way without knowing how to fix it just yet. Sure wish I had enough rep to chat. Rep requirements seem silly. There's also another potential issue. In the billed65+flushot and billedadultflushot files, the MRNs are followed by a tab, and a date of service (when they got the shot). Will this prevent the code from functioning like it should?

Comment: Can you help me out once again?